# Conversion failed when converting the varchar/nvarchar value to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT CONVERT([int],11.25)-CONVERT([int],'10.25')
```

How to avoid error and return 1 as result.

This is not a duplicate question.  The similar question you referred is complex when comparing to my simple query question.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: You do realise `10.25` is not an `int` right?

Comment: Yes, I would like to make it as int and would like to return integer as output without any errors.

Comment: @Dale K, could you please post your decimal(9,2) as answer.  I will mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using the implicit behaviour of the `CONVERT` function, why not use the correct function, e.g. `ROUND`

```
SELECT ROUND(11.25, 0)-ROUND(CONVERT(DECIMAL(9,2),'10.25'), 0)
```